# Como checar a existência de multiplos valores em uma string com JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Para buscar apenas um valor fixo em uma string eu posso utilizar a funcão JavaScript [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf), exemplo:

```
var string = "Oberyn se vinga";
string.indexOf('vinga') >= 0 //retorna true ou false
```

Mas como eu faria para verificar vários valores contra uma string? Exemplo:

```
var string = "Oberyn se vinga de Sor Clegane";
string.indexOf(['vinga','de','Clegane'])
```

Aparentemente a função `indexOf()` não aceita arrays na busca.

A única forma seria utilizando *regex*? Ou existe alguma função específica para estes casos?

Comment: Você quer receber `true` se *pelo menos* um dos valores foi encontrado? Ou algo mais complexo (como offset de cada valor)?

Comment: @bfavaretto não tinha me atentado para estas duas possibilidades, mas acho que o offset de cada valor seria mais interessante, já que com ele já da para verificar se retornou alguma coisa ou não.

Comment: Vale notar `indexOf()` retorna o índice da substring na string original. Não retorna `true` ou `false`. De fato, no seu exemplo a comparação retornará `false` porque `string.indexOf('vinga')` é 10. A comparação ideal seria `string.indexOf('vinga') >= 0`, pois `indexOf()` retornará -1 se não encontrar o índice. Ademais... ei, olha o spoiler, cara :P

Comment: @brandizzi bem lembrado, corrigi lá. Sobre o spoiler, pode ser ou pode não ser, depende do ponto de vista, haha

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Uma maneira de fazer é usar [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) para aplicar o `indexOf` a cada item da array. Por exemplo:

```
var string = "Oberyn se vinga de Sor Clegane";
var buscar = ['vinga','de','Clegane'];
var indices = buscar.map(String.prototype.indexOf.bind(string));
// [10, 16, 23]
```

O [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) é necessário para o `indexOf` saber em qual string ele precisa operar. Tanto `bind` quanto `map` são recursos do ECMAScript 5, portanto não irão funcionar em implementações mais antigas (como a do IE8). Mas os artigos da MDN que indiquei oferecem *polyfills* para essas implementações.